# Is it safe to use ssh keys generated inside of Docker as "fake" SSH keys?

Tags: docker, ssh

I wanted simply to succeed a private key parser, and I just created ssh keys with `ssh-keygen` inside of a Docker container:

```
docker run -it --rm circleci/node:11
# Inside of docker
ssh-keygen
# Accepted default values
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
# And copied and used this value
```

Do these new keys contain any information about my machine (Outside of Docker)?

Is it dangerous if I share the content of that `id_rsa`?

I do not really need that the ssh key I use for my tests are functional, just that it complies with the private key parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that it's a dangerous practice in general, but as you've described the problem, the specific instance won't cause security issues.

An ssh RSA key is "just" a couple of numbers plus a comment string.  (In much the same way that a physical house key is "just" a chunk of metal with some grooves and notches cut in it.)  If you generated an RSA key pair, discarded the public key, and published the private key, it wouldn't be intrinsically dangerous, since that private key doesn't technically authenticate you to anything.

Still, if you're in the habit of publishing ssh private keys, it opens the possibility that at some point you'll publish a "real" key in your "normal" process, and that would be bad.  I'd suggest that's not actually a best practice and you should treat every private key as though it had root permissions on your servers.

(This has nothing at all to do with Docker, except that if you `ssh-keygen` inside a container, it will usually live in the container-private filesystem and it will be a little harder to leak.)